# Android application hangup when i implemeting Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

i'm newbie for using this android library, below code is my simple impelemented Retrofit library, after running project i dont get any error but my project hangup and doesnt work.

verbose logcat messages after use Retrofit Call function:

```
06-04 03:10:44.647 21694-21709/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 196320(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 36(1935KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 85MB/90MB, paused 7.388ms total 52.997ms
06-04 03:10:44.802 21694-21704/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.926ms
06-04 03:10:44.844 21694-21709/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135992(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 31(1674KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 85MB/90MB, paused 6.324ms total 49.940ms
06-04 03:10:45.185 21694-21709/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 101MB to 96MB
06-04 03:10:45.185 21694-21709/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 246201(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 59(3MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 85MB/96MB, paused 6.412ms total 212.381ms
06-04 03:10:45.185 21694-21694/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 119.899ms for cause Alloc
06-04 03:10:45.476 21694-21709/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 240528(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 48(2MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 86MB/94MB, paused 7.318ms total 54.547ms
06-04 03:10:45.476 21694-21694/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 35.245ms for cause Alloc
06-04 03:10:51.268 21694-21702/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Thread[5,tid=21702,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef60d400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-04 03:10:51.603 21694-21702/ir.pishguy.signalpresentationproject I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

My code:

`SignalProvider` class:

```
public class SignalProvider {
    private SignalServices signalServices;
    public SignalProvider(){
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(ClientSettings.SignalWebBaseUrl)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        signalServices = retrofit.create(SignalServices.class);
    }
    public SignalServices getServices(){
        return signalServices;
    }
}
```

`SignalServices` interface class:

```
public interface SignalServices {
    @GET("storeLists")
    Call<List<Store>> getStoreLists();
}
```

`ClientSettings` class:

```
public class ClientSettings {
    public static final String SignalWebBaseUrl = "http://192.168.1.35/signal/public/";
}
```

and then i'm using them from activity by this methods:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initUI();

    SignalProvider signalProvider = new SignalProvider();
    SignalServices signalServices = signalProvider.getServices();
    Store          store = new Store();

    Call<List<Store>> call = signalServices.getStoreLists();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Store>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Store>> call, Response<List<Store>> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Store>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

after running project and after some minute my app crached

Comment: If your app crashes, your should see an actual error.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you are right, unfortunately i dont see any error after crash on LogCat

Comment: Well, I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. The only thing that would cause a memory crash here is if the server never closes the response stream and you are reading data indefinitely.

Comment: Check the logcat before closing the "App has crashed" in the device. Sometimes Android Studio clean the app logcat after it dies.

Comment: @cricket_007 after change `targetSdkVersion` from `23` to `22` on Gradle, problem solved

Comment: Not sure how that fixes anything because you are still compiling with the same SDK but okay.

Comment: You should be needing some dangerous permission at some point in your code, mind sharing the Manifest? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

**Problem Solved**

after some debug application, i changed `targetSdkVersion` from `23` to `22` on Gradle and then problem solved